# Tabulate multiple variables with common prefix using a local macro

Tags: loops, stata, stata-macros

I have a number of variables whose name begins with the prefix `indoor`. What comes after `indoor` is not numeric (that would make everything simpler).

I would like a tabulation for each of these variables.

My code is the following:

```
local indoor indoor*  
foreach i of local indoor {  
    tab `i' group, col freq exact chi2  
}
```

The problem is that `indoor` in the `foreach` command resolves to `indoor*` and not to the list of the `indoor` questions, as I hoped. For this reason, the `tab` command is followed by too many variables (it can only handle two) and this results in an error.

The simple fix is to substitute the first command with:

```
local indoor <full list of indoor questions>
```

But this is what I would like to avoid, that is to have to find all the names for these variables and then paste them in the code. It seems there is a quicker fix for this but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with

```
foreach i of var `indoor' {
   tab `i' group, col freq exact chi2
}
```

Comment: This mixes up the syntax of -foreach- a bit.  The help manual indicates that you want to use "foreach i of varlist var1 var2" where var1 and var2 are variables OR use "foreach i of local indoor", not combine them as in the example above.  This _works_ in this example, however, if you had a list in the local `indoor' that did not adhere to the rules of naming variables in a -varlist-, then varlist expansion in "foreach i of var `indoor'" would fail and leave the user confused.

Comment: It's not SO bad, as long as you understand that Stata unpacks a local/global macro before executing the command.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to use `ds` or `unab` to create the varlist expansion before asking Stata to loop over values in the `foreach` loop.

Here's an example of each:

```
    ******************! BEGIN EXAMPLE

** THIS FIRST SECTION SIMPLY CREATES SOME FAKE DATA & INDOOR VARS **
    clear
    set obs 10000
    local suffix `c(ALPHA)'
    token `"`suffix'"'
    while "`1'" != "" {
        g indoor`1'`2'`3' =  1+int((5-1+1)*runiform())
        lab var indoor`1'`2'`3' "Indoor Values for `1'`2'`3'"
        mac shift 1
        }
    g group = rbinomial(1,.5)
    lab var group "GROUP TYPE"

** NOW, YOU SHOULD HAVE A BUNCH OF FAKE INDOOR 
**VARS WITH ALPHA, NOT NUMERIC SUFFIXES

desc  indoor*
```

**USE `ds` TO CREATE YOUR VARLIST FOR THE `foreach` LOOP:

```
    ds indoor*
    di "`r(varlist)'"
    local indoorvars `r(varlist)'

    local n  0
    foreach i of local indoorvars {
```

**LET'S CLEAN UP YOUR TABLES A BIT WITH SOME HEADERS VIA `display`

```
    local ++n
    di in red "--------------------------------------------"
    di in red "Table `n':  `:var l `i'' by `:var l group'"
    di in red "--------------------------------------------"
```

**YOUR `tab` TABLES

```
    tab `i' group, col freq chi2 exact nolog nokey
    }
    ******************! END EXAMPLE
```

OR using `unab` instead:

```
******************! BEGIN EXAMPLE
unab indoorvars: indoor*
di "`indoorvars'"

local n  0
foreach i of local indoorvars {
local ++n
di in red "--------------------------------------------"
di in red "Table `n':  `:var l `i'' by `:var l group'"
di in red "--------------------------------------------"

tab `i' group, col freq chi2 nokey  //I turned off exact to speed things up
}

******************! END EXAMPLE
```

The advantages of `ds` come into play if you want to select your indoor vars using a tricky selection rule, like selecting indoor vars based on information in the variable label or some other characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

This would work. It is almost identical to the code in the question.

```
unab indoor : indoor*
foreach i of local indoor {
  tab `i' group, col freq exact chi2
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach v of varlist indoo* {
do sth with `v'
}
```