# how do I loop through file names in stata

Tags: stata

1) Is it possible to create a vector of strings in stata? 2) If yes, is it then possible to loop through the elements in this vector, performing commands on each element?

To create a single string in stata I know you do this:

```
    local x = "a string"
```

But I have about 200 data files I need to loop through, and they are not conveniently named with consecutive suffixes like "_2000" "_2001" "_2002" etc.  In fact there is no rhyme or reason to the file names, but I do have a list of them which I could easily cut and paste into a string vector, and then call the elements of this vector one by one, as one might do in MATLAB.

Is there a way to do this in stata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure --  You just create a list using a typical local call.  If you don't put quotes around the whole thing your lists can be really long.

```
local mylist aaa bbb "cc c" dd ee ff
```

Then you just use `foreach`.

```
foreach filename of local mylist {
  use `"`filename'"'
}
```

The double quotes (`` `" "' ``) are used because one of the filenames has quotes around it because of the space. This is a touch faster than putting  `` foreach filename in `mylist' { `` on the first line.

If you want to manipulate your list, see [`help macrolists`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?macrolists).

Related questions have been asked >1 time on stackoverflow:

- [In Stata how do you assign a long list of variable names to a local macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701823/in-stata-how-do-you-assign-a-long-list-of-variable-names-to-a-local-macro/7827048#7827048)
- [Equivalent function of R's "%in%" for Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091426/equivalent-function-of-rs-in-for-stata/5093094#5093094)

Comment: This won't work if you have `local mylist "a aa" bbb "cc c" dd ee "f f"` for instance, because the outer quotes will get stripped: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-10/msg00285.html

Answer (score 8):

On top of Keith's answer: you can also get the list of files in a directory with

```
    local myfilelist    : dir . files "*.dta"
```

or more generally

```
    local theirfilelist : dir <directory name> files <file mask>
```

See `help extended_fcn`.

Answer (score 3):

What many people might want the combination of the two as I did. Here it is:

```
* Create a local containing the list of files. 
local myfilelist : dir "." files "*.dta"

* Or manually create the list by typing in the filenames.
local myfilelist "file1.dta" "file2.dta" "file3.dta"

* Then loop through them as you need.
foreach filename of local myfilelist {
  use "`filename'"
}
```

I hope that helps. Note that locals/macros are limited by [67,784 characters](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-06/msg00330.html)--watch out for this when you have a really long list of files or really long filenames.

Comment: Information here on maximum macro length is very out of date, unless your Stata itself is very out of date. Consult `help limits` in your Stata for what applies to you.