# Loop through a list of files in stata

Tags: loops, filenames, stata

I am trying to loop through a list of filenames in Stata. Filenames are of the type: `CityName.dta`, `CityNamePrices.dta`, etc.

I tool a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067768/how-do-i-loop-through-file-names-in-stata) similar question but was not able to adapt it to my setup.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
local mylist Atlanta Boston Charlotte Chicago 

foreach filename of local mylist {

use `"`filename'"'.dta
*Do some stuff here

use `"`filename'"'Prices.dta
*Do some more stuff here

clear

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filenames are specified incorrectly. Instead, try this:

```
use `"`filename'.dta"'
use `"`filename'Prices.dta"'
```